# Using SSL based tcp/ip sockets in Android

Tags: android, ssl, tcp, jsse

I 'm trying to Secure my TCP/IP based Socket connection using SSL for Android platform.
here is some snippet from my code:

## Client Side:

```
  SSLSocketFactory sslFact = null;  
    SSLContext ctx;
    KeyStore ks;

    char[] passphrase = "hosttest".toCharArray();

    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ks.load(SSLActivity.mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hosttestcert), passphrase);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);

    ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null,tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    sslFact = ctx.getSocketFactory();

    mySocket = (SSLSocket)sslFact.createSocket();
    mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 7891),1000);
```

## Server Side:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslSrvFact = null;  
SSLContext ctx;
KeyManagerFactory kmf;
KeyStore ks;
// Load the self-signed server certificate

char[] passphrase = "hosttest".toCharArray();

ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
ks.load(SSLActivity.mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hosttestcert), passphrase);
kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

kmf.init(ks, passphrase);

// Create a SSLContext with the certificate

ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),null, null);

sslSrvFact = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
myServerSocket =(SSLServerSocket)sslSrvFact.createServerSocket(port);
```

When I call the accept() socket call from server, I'm getting the following exception:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites.
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledCipherSuites(OpenSSLServerSocketImpl.java:241)
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLServerSocketImpl.accept(OpenSSLServerSocketImpl.java:186)  
at com.aricent.ssltesst.ApplinkTCPServer$1.run(ApplinkTCPServer.java:189)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm following this post for generating my certs and keystore:
 http://randomizedsort.blogspot.in/2010/09/step-to-step-guide-to-programming.html 
please suggest if I'm missing something or something else needs to be done for the keystore on Android platform.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have the same logic with what I did, in my application I have 1 JKS Keystore generated, which then I used a converter to duplicate a copy of BKS keystore for Android. If this is what you're doing, here's my Server Side codes:

```
String keyStorePath = "absolute path to your JKS keystore file";
String keyStorePass = "keystore password";

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePass);

SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(port_number);

while (true) {
    new ClientThread((SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept()).start();
}
```